# SQL Reporting Services Trying to use embed code to access database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I’m trying to open a data base on embed vb code.  On the `MyConnection.Open()` I get a error saying

> Warning   1   [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the
>   textrun ‘Textbox1.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error:
>   Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.   C:\Users\tedpottel\Documents\Visual Studio

My datasource in the report is `Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=bw`
vb code is:

```
Public Function TestData  () As Boolean
Dim MyConnection As System.Data.SQLClient.SqlConnection
Dim MyCommand As System.Data.SQLClient.SqlCommand
MyConnection = New System.Data.SQLClient.SqlConnection("server=(local);Initial Catalog=bw")
MyConnection.Open() 
MyConnection.Close() 
return True
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First result on Google for "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission":

> Hi Joost,
>
> Based on your description, this issue was probably related to the Code Access Security. Please refer to the following articles to configure the assembly to make sure it is set to fulltrust. Request for the permission of type 'SecurityPermission' failed:
> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/floditt/archive/2009/08/10/request-for-the-permission-of-type-securitypermission-failed.aspx

Follow the link for information on how to configure your code to run at full trust.

> The tool CasPol.exe (part of the .Net SDK) will help you to identify the CodeGroup that the System.Security assembly belongs to. In the GAC folder of this assembly I did a CasPol –rsg (resolvesGroup) on this assembly:
>
> Now we can see that this assembly belongs to the Microsoft_Strong_Name (line 3 in the CodeGroup excerpt) and is configured for FullTrust. With the –rsp (resolvesPermissions) you can visualize all permissions that are granted to this assembly (as defined in the FullTrust named PermissionSet):
>
> When the exception was raised, this assembly was configured to ‘Nothing’ (line 3 of the NamedPermissionSets excerpt). The problem was resolved by granting this assembly FullTrust.